# Subgroup complemented by a double coset of a non-maximal subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup.  Then the action of $G$ on $G/H$ is $2$-transitive if and only if $H$ only has two double cosets in $G$, as follows:

$\forall g \in G \setminus H: G = HgH \cup H.$

I am interested in a variation of this.  Suppose we have groups $G > H > K$.  Consider the following condition on $(G,H,K)$:

$(*) \; \forall g \in G \setminus H: G = KgK \cup H.$

The motivation for me is that in a boundary-$2$-transitive action on a leafless tree, we get this structure where $(G,H,K)$ are stabilizers of a vertex, arc and ray of the tree.  Probably it arises in some other contexts as well.

Has $(*)$ has been studied in the literature (probably in the context of finite groups where classifying things is plausible, but it could be interesting for infinite groups too), and if so, does it have a standard name?  It is easy to make examples of $(*)$ by starting with a group $G$ acting $2$-transitively on a set $X$ and then forming a wreath product $M \wr_X G$, taking $H = M^X \rtimes G_x$ and $K \ge M^{X \setminus x} \rtimes G_x$.  So I am more interested in results/examples for groups that are not like this, say where $H$ has trivial core in $G$.

The only closely related property I found in the literature is for a permutation group to be imprimitive of rank $3$: that is, we have $G/K$ such that $K$ is not maximal, $K$ has trivial core and there are exactly three double cosets of $K$ in $G$.  We then find

$G = KgK \cup KhK \cup K$

where $H$ is the unique maximal subgroup of $G$ containing $K$, $g$ is any element of $G \setminus H$ and $h$ is any element of $H \setminus K$.  So this is a special case of $(*)$, and for finite groups a great deal is known about rank $3$ actions.  But as far as I can tell, the situation $(*)$ does not impose any upper bound on the number of double cosets of $K$ in $G$.  More broadly, in the rank $3$ case of $(*)$, the action of $H$ on $H/K$ is $2$-transitive, but I don't know what permutational properties $(*)$ by itself (or $(*)$ plus the assumption that $H$ has trivial core) imposes on the action of $H$ on $H/K$.

I managed to rule out enough cases (using the classification of finite $2$-transitive permutation groups) for the specific application I had in mind, but it would be good to know if there is some nontrivial general theory of the situation $(*)$, even just for finite groups.

Comment: I am not sure it helps, but your condition seems to be equivalent ( given that $G$  acts doubly transitively on the cosets of $H$, as you already noted), to requiring that the non - trivial irreducible constituents of the permutation character of $H$ on the cosets of $K$ all induce irreducibly to $G$, and different auch irreducibles of $H$ induce to different irreducibles of $G$.